# Exported SVG has no fill or stroke in the code

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to manipulate/animate a stroked SVG icon that I've made; however, when I export it as an SVG with Illustrator, I see this:

```
<path d="M8,37.3c1-1.5 ...>
```

When I would expect something like:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M8,37.3c1-1.5 ...>
```

So when I try to animate the stroke using the [dasharray](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) method, it doesn't work. When I try to add a stroke to the code like the one above, it creates an ugly outline on the shape.

The options themselves look like this:

[image]

I'm wondering how to either export the SVG better, or edit the code properly to create the stroke (not the fill). If any more information is needed from me, let me know.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so what programming question do you have? If not it's off topic.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle (or other sandbox) for this?  Generally, adding fill and stroke properties to the element with CSS should do the trick - if that's not working it's probably due to something unusual about the particular path commands being created.